# printing the first letter of a variable returns a number?

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to Ruby and was mucking around with the basics and came across a problem.

Which was that when I tried to print the first letter of a variable it printed a number instead.

the code was.

```
name = "Max"

print name[0]
```

but instead of printing the letter M, it would print 77?

could someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Odd. When I do it, I get `M => nil` (`M` is the output, and `nil` is what `print` returns), not `77`. You could try `puts name[0]`, which will put a newline after printing it. There must be more to your context. What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: thanks, i tried that but it still prints 77

Comment: There's something else going on with `name` in your context. Does this happen if you just enter `irb` and type the two lines above at the `irb` prompt? What version of ruby?

Comment: It's not a version issue. I just tried 1.8.7 and my `print name` outputs "Max". Please, explain your context or at least try the little test I described (just doing this in a fresh `irb` session). Or perhaps what your code really looks like isn't exactly what you're showing in your problem statement.

Comment: I was trying to assign name[0] to the variable first_letter, but when i did it just gave it the value of 77 instead of M

Comment: Well, that's different than what your problem states.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 and earlier return fixnum for `'Max'[0]`. "[`str[fixnum] => fixnum or nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html)". Ruby 1.9+ returns a character: "[`str[fixnum] => new_str or nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)"

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of this operator is different across various versions of Ruby. You're probably using an older one, in which case this is to be expected.

Here's an excerpt from the [docs for Ruby 1.8.7's String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

> If passed a single Fixnum, returns the code of the character at that
>   position.

This has been changed and the newer versions of Ruby (1.9.x and above, according to [this site](http://ruby.about.com/od/strings/a/Indexing-Strings.htm) ) simply print the character as a String. See [the docs for Ruby 2.1.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

> If passed a single index, returns a substring of one character at that
>   index.

Ruby 1.9.3, which I happen to have installed on the machine I'm using displays exactly the same behavior:

```
"Mwada"[0]
=> "M"

"Mwada"[0].class
=> String
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's ruby 1.8.x, run `#chr` on a number representing the character:

```
"Mwada"[0].chr # => "M"
```

If it's ruby 1.9.x and above, everything will work as you would expect it to:

```
"Mwada"[0] # => "M"
```

Answer (score 1):

Humm, I ran your question through irb (interactive ruby console) and got 'M' when looking for name[0]. You can open irb by simply typing irb from command line and test this for yourself.

```
irb > name = "Max"
=> "Max" 
irb > print name[0]
M => nil
```

Can you tell me more about the context in which you requested name[0]? Could name have been reassigned to something else? Are you calling .to_i (convert to integer) anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this issue from a Ruby book that includes information on Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. The book is called The Ruby Programming Language Book by David Flanagan & Yukihiro Matsumoto.

Well the book says: "In Ruby 1.8, a string is like an array of bytes or 8-bit character codes

```
s = 'hello' # Ruby 1.8
s[0]        # 104: the ASCII character code for the first character 'h'
```

Ruby 1.9 returns single-character strings rather than character

```
s = 'hello' # Ruby 1.9
s[0]        # 'h': the first character of the string, as a string
```

(please note some text was left out in the quote above)

In relation to your question directly. I also tested String.bytes.to_a method on 
'Max', in my Ruby 1.9 environment.

```
print name.bytes.to_a
[77, 97, 120] => nil
```

and it printed the ASCII codes for 'Max', 77 is the ASCII code for 'M'

[ASCII Codes](http://www.asciitable.com/)

I am quite new Ruby programmer as well. I am also learning Ruby so I have found the book above worthwhile, although I have so far managed to read only the first 70 pages or so, I'll definitely try to finish the book :-)